# Stepper motor controlled by Arduino does 4 times more steps

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, robotics

I had a simple setup: Arduino Uno, stepper motor NEMA 17 and a driver for it. All I needed to do is to rotate my motor by a certain number of degrees. It all worked perfectly, but one day I pluged it into another outlet and it began to smoke and wires' isolation started melting. I don't know what's wrong with this outlet, maybe grounding problems.
Anyways, it worked fine with other outlets, but it started rotating 4 times more then I need it to. Not like this is a huge deal, I can just divide abount of steps by 4, but it limits possible amount of steps that I can use and I really need precision here.
Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

Stepper motor over rotation can be caused by supplying a higher voltage than the motor is rated for. Its quite possible that whatever happened which caused things to start melting and smoking either was a short, or if not, caused a short. In either cause I'm guessing that short is supplying to much voltage and causing over rotation. You might be able to check this with a multimeter, but its unlikely the components will return to normal operation.